What is the dimension of the vector space of operators M, where M(T) is the matrix of the linear map T between two vector spaces?
I'm currently reading Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th edition and I have the following questions:
Let us assume we are dealing with finite-dimensional vector spaces and we use the following notation:

$\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ - denotes the set of linear maps from $V$ to $W$;
The vector space of all m-by-n matrices is $\textbf{F}^{m,n}$.

For $T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, the operator $\mathcal{M}(T)$ is the matrix of the linear map $T$. It can be shown that $\mathcal{M}$ is an isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and $\textbf{F}^{m,n}$, where dim$V=n$ and dim$W=m$. This can be used to prove the theorem which states that dim$\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ = (dim$V$)(dim$W$) $=nm$.
But we also have, using the standard definition of addition and scalar multiplication for matrices, that $\mathcal{M}$ is a linear map and $\mathcal{M}\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(V,W),\textbf{F}^{m,n})$.
Am I then correct to say:
dim$\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(V,W),\textbf{F}^{m,n}) = (nm)^{2}$?
I.e. all the operators $\mathcal{M}$ are vectors in a vector space of dimension $(nm)^{2}$? If so, is this result significant in any way and does the space $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(V,W),\textbf{F}^{m,n})$ have a specific interpretation?
EDIT: I realize that there is a way in which my question might not be stated correctly or might lead to inconsistencies, namely because the matrix $\mathcal{M}(T)$ for $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is defined in a specific way with respect to a basis $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ of $V$ and a basis $w_{1},...,w_{m}$ of $W$. I.e. the definition of the operator $M$ is dependent on the choice of these bases.

When you wrote “finite vector spaces”, did you mean “finite-dimensional vector spaces”?

Yes. I'll edit the question to say that.

yes for the dimension, you can just write down the basis is enough.

The basis of what? @lee

For convenience, I'll use the notation $\mathcal U_{m,n} = \mathcal L(\mathcal L(V,W), \mathbf F^{m,n})$. No, this is not any kind of standard notation.
Yes, it is correct to say that $\dim \mathcal L(\mathcal L(V,W), \mathbf F^{m,n}) = (mn)^2$. Indeed, all maps of the form
$$
\Phi:\mathcal L(V,W) \to \mathbf F^{m,n}\\
\Phi(T) = \mathcal L(T;B_1,B_2)
$$
(for some choice of bases $B_1,B_2$ of $U,V$ respectively) are elements of the same $(mn)^2$-dimensional space. You might find it interesting that these elements of the form $\Phi$ are sufficient to span the entirety of $\mathcal U_{m,n}$ and that, in the case where $\mathbf F \in \{\Bbb C,\Bbb R\}$ these maps form a manifold of dimension $m^2 + n^2 - 1$ within the ambient space $\mathcal U_{m,n}$.
Is your result regarding the dimension of this vector space significant in any way? On its own, I'd say that it's not particularly significant, but it is an important thing to know in the study of these spaces. Working within spaces like $\mathcal U_{m,n}$ (or at least spaces that can be naturally identified with $\mathcal U_{m,n}$) is important for some areas of math including differential geometry and quantum information theory. In the context of quantum information theory, certain elements of $\mathcal L(\Bbb C^{n,n}, \Bbb C^{n,n})$ are called quantum channels.

Thank you, Ben! This is very interesting!
